# inserting timestamp in mysql table in python

Tags: python, mysql

`bid`, `best_bid_quantity` are `floats`, `target_date` is set as `timestamp` in my db.

#### get timestamp

```
target_date_time_ms = (k.lastRestRequestTimestamp) 

base_datetime = datetime.datetime( 1970, 1, 1 )

delta = datetime.timedelta( 0, 0, 0, target_date_time_ms )

target_date = base_datetime + delta
```

#### timestamp = target_date

```
db = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost",    # your host, usually localhost
                         user="root",         # your username
                         passwd="lolilol",  # your password
                         db="test")        # name of the data base

cur = db.cursor()

try:

   cur.execute("""INSERT INTO test1 (heure, prix, quantite) VALUES ({},{},{})""".format(target_date, bid, best_bid_quantity))
   db.commit()

except:
    print('did not insert')
    db.rollback()

db.close()
```

#### error --> it goes to except when I add the target_date

Comment: Try getting your exception to print out more info, like: `except Exception as e: print(e)`. Then tell us what the exact error is.

Comment: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '13:25:34.218000,0.071,24.434)' at line 1")

Comment: What is the value of `target_date_time_ms`?

Comment: the value is 1530711319886 in ms

Answer (score 1):

Try using `time.strftime()`:

```
time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', target_date.timetuple())
```

The `.timetuple()` method is required to convert the `datetime.datetime` object of `target_date` into a `time_struct` struct, which can then be used in the call to `time.strftime`.